# Php wordpress catching post of a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

So i have this page in wordpress:

http://newsite.rifraf.be/?page_id=89

Since this page needs to be linked to my xml dbase from my mobile app i need to be able to catch the post and throw it in the xml.

I know of the command save_post but cannot seem to find how i can use this to catch the post of my specific page.

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved this myself, since the page is always updated i get the id in the post.php file

```
if(get_the_ID() == 89)
    {
var_dump($post->post_content);
}
```

I have found get_the_ID() after some searching in the wordpress codex